# Aligning Text Boxes in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to align text boxes in silverlight using C# .In my application two textboxes are getting overlapped . I am using Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place them in a `StackPanel`.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="120">
    <TextBox Width="120">
</StackPanel>
```

produces two text boxes one above the other.

Another option is use a second grid with two rows or two columns and place a text box in each, this allows you share out the available space of the cell in provided by the outer Grid.